# Compilation fails when passing array with missing initializers as argument

Tags: c++, c++03

When I try to compile

```
template<int dim> 
struct Foo
{
    Foo(const int (&i)[dim]) {}
};

int main()
{
    Foo<2> f = Foo<2>((int[2]){0});  // line 9
    return 0;
}
```

I get the compilation error

> test.cpp:9:31: error: no matching function for call to ‘Foo<2>::Foo(int [1])’

Apparently, the argument I pass to the constructor is regarded as an `int[1]`. Why isn't it regarded as an `int[2]` (which could then be casted to a const reference as expected by the constructor)? Shouldn't the missing elements be value-initialized according to 8.5.1 (7)?

After all, replacing line 9 with

```
int arg[2] = {0};
Foo<2> f = Foo<2>(arg);
```

lets me compile the program. Additionally, when I try to pass `(const int [2]){0, 0, 0}` to the constructor, I get the error message *too many initializers for ‘const int [2]’*, so apparently, the compiler *is* trying to construct a `const int[2]`.

Somebody please shed some light on this unintuitive behavior.

Comment: Apparently not. If it where, it would compile. I'm looking for the reason why it is not C++03.

Comment: It compiles fine with `g++ (GCC) 4.7.0` without `-std=c++0x`

Comment: It fails on g++ 4.6.3 with `-std=c++03`, with `-std=c++03` and without any `-sdt`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The construct `(int[2]){0}` is a C99 compound literal, which is not part of C++. How particular compilers interpret in the context of C++ is anyone's guess (or a matter of examining the source code).

PS. OK, it seems that gcc 4.7/gcc 4.8/clang-3.1 handle it quite sensibly - the type of the compound literal is the same as the C99 standard specifies it.

I guess the OP compiler is a bit older.

Comment: @Oswald, yep, I see. Apparently, it's compiler bug, fixed since 4.6.3.